# <?php echo file_get_contents how to get content in a certain tag

Tags: php, url, web, tags

```
<?php echo file_get_contents ("http://www.google.com/"); ?>
```

but I only want to get the contents of the  tag in the url...how to do that...?
I need to echo the content between a  tag....not the whole page

Comment: What do you mean "contents of the tag in the url"?

Comment: use curl to read data, sometime file_get_contents does't work.

Comment: you need to parse the code and get the contents in tag you want

Comment: like between the code <table> </table >

Answer (score 1):

Refer this [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) which also help you.

You may also use user define function instead of file_get_contents():

```
function get_content($URL){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;
  }


 echo get_content('http://example.com');
```

Hope, it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to extract content from a specific html tag in the file. For this you can use regular expressions. However view the following link to parse an HTML document file:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0):

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$url = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947331/php-echo-file-get-contents-how-to-get-content-in-a-certain-tag";

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $element) {
    echo $element->nodeValue.'<br/>';
} 

exit;
```

More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

There you can see how to select elements by `id` or `class`, how to get elements' attribute values etc.

**Note:** It's better to get content via [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of `get_file_contents`. For example:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $data;
}
```

Also note that on some websites you have to specify options like `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` etc., otherwise the content may not be returned.

Here are the other options: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php